# Removing a Route parameter from an ActionLink in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am having a bit of a problem with a RouteData Value lingering in my View and making my `@Html.ActionLink(...)` look a bit ugly.

In my routes I have this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SubItemLinked",
    url: "SubItems/{subitemId}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "DeepDownItems", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { subitemId = "^[0-9]*$", id = "^[0-9]*$" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ItemLinked",
    url: "Items/{itemId}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "SubItems", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { itemId = "^[0-9]*$", id = "^[0-9]*$" }
);
```

The above allows me to have Urls like these:

- `~/Items/3` <= will show all SubItems for Item number 3
- `~/Items/3/SubItems/Create` <= exactly what you would expect
- `~/SubItems/5` <= to show all DeepDownItems of SubItem number 5

and so on...

Now, of course the `DeepDownItems` controller will recognise the `subitemId` parameter and use it for retrieval of stuff from the DB. Problem is that if I want to put a link back to the SubItems list, I don't need this subitemId anymore and I need to remove it from the RouteValueDictionary.

As an example of the flow, let's assume I go to `~/SubItems/5`, I see the list of all `DeepDownItems` of SubItem 5, which is correct. In that View I have this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Go Back", "Index", "SubItems", new { itemId = ViewBag.itemid, subitemId = String.Empty }, null)
```

This should generate, according to the Routes, a link to `~/Items/3`. I had to put `subitemId = String.Empty` or it would have matched with the top route. Problem is that the url being generated is like this `~/Items/3?subitemId=5`, so basically is matching the Route correctly but then it is not clearing the `subitemId` parameter as instructed.

Do you have any ideas on how to do it? Notice that I have other links (Edit/Create) on the View that rely on that parameter being present and added automatically so I would really like to only remove it from that link rather than the whole Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the same issue I've been fighting for the last few hours, but if it is: Try using `@Html.RouteLink` where you can specify which route to create a link from.

Something like the following, if I've managed to decipher your example :P

```
@Html.RouteLink("Go Back", "ItemLinked", new {
        controller = "SubItems",
        action = "Index", 
        itemId = ViewBag.itemid,
    })
```